# Listener for wifi

Tags: android-wifi, wifimanager

I want to make notification when wifi signal strength is weak.
If there isn't a listener for wifi , can I create a custom listener for wifi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be register a listener for the RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION as can be found in the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION).